# Python requires root to run, but Kivy crashes using sudo

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, kivy, sudo

I've searched online to find answers to this, but I've come up short. Other examples are different enough to not get me to a solution. This is on a Raspberry Pi 3b, Raspbian, Jessie.

I have a kivy app that uses a bluetooth (ble) peripheral device. My BLE class has to scan for BLE devices which requires `root` privileges. The BLE class works using `sudo` outside of kivy so I don't 'think' there is a fundamental problem with the BLE code. FYI, the BLE class uses bluepy (btle). In order to get the peripheral working correctly I have to run:

```
scanner = btle.Scanner()
dev = scanner.scan(3)
```

The `scan` requires running as `root`. If I didn't need it I would remove it, but then the behavior of the program changes.

My problem is that running my program (w/ BLE class AND kivy) from command prompt like this: `python3 FS_run.py` runs the application w/out connecting to the BLE peripheral. However, when I run it like this: `sudo python3 FS_run.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FS_run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named 'kivy'
```

I've seen a lot of posts where successfully running kivy w/ `sudo` makes the buttons not work. I've changed the permissions (chmod) of the BLE class file and tried running again w/out `sudo`, but that didn't help. I'm open to other suggestions to circumvent the use of `sudo`. Perhaps running the BLE in a subprocess, but I wouldn't know how to make it join the rest of the program. Also, I'm fairly new to BLE, I just got the BLE class to work yesterday. Suffice it to say I'm a bit out of my league here.

I'm not a linux guy so I am not sure where to focus my energy to solve this. Not sure if this is helpful, but I saw this on another post so I'll just add it:
`which python3` gives `/usr/bin/python3`
`sudo which python3` gives `/usr/bin/python3`

EDIT:

`python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` 
prints different output than when run with `sudo`. 
`'/home/pi/kivy'` is missing when run with `sudo`. How do I go about fixing this?

EDIT 2:

Other posts said this fixed it:
`sudo cp /home/pi/.kivy/config.ini /root/.kivy/config.ini`

Didn't work for me. I got:

`cp: cannot create regularfile '/root/.kivy/config.ini': No such file or directory`

So then I manually created the .kivy directory in root and then did a sudo cp to copy the file over. Still does not work.

Comment: If you do `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and then the same thing with `sudo`, what output do you get?

Comment: I'm thinking out loud here, but probably the issue is with the environment, when `sudo` elevates the privileges it cleans the environment, so if you have virtualenv or custom PATH the elevated program will not know about it... TLDR; try `sudo -E` to run your program

Comment: It's been a long time since I touched this stuff...  `scan` doesn't require full root access, it only needs access to raw sockets (if I remember correctly).  You may be able to make the .py file an executable and then use `setcap` to allow raw sockets.

Comment: If you add the directory for kivy explicitly in your python script? `import os;
path = 'the path you want';
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'+path`; (must be before the import for kivy)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but so far none of these have worked. I also tried setting the KIVY_HOME variable, but that did not work either. Anyone else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding at the end of the file `"/root/profile"`
the line :

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/Documents/kivy/kivy:$PYTHONPATH
```

Then before launching the app :

```
sudo su
source ~/.profile
```

I don't know if it helped but I have also :

```
sudo cp /home/pi/.kivy/config.ini /root/.kivy/config.ini
```